# NSDateFormatter string

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

What is the `NSDateFormatter` string for the following date/Time : `02/22/2011 10:43:00 AM`

Basically what I wanted was to read a string `02/22/2011 19:00:23 PM`, convert it to `NSDate` and then print is appropriately. My previous attempt:

```
NSDateFormatter* dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

NSDate* dt3 = [dtFormatter dateFromString:@"02/22/2011 19:00:23 PM"];
NSString* strDate3 = [dtFormatter stringFromDate:dt3];
NSLog(@"Third = %@",strDate3);
```

Every time I tried that it would print NULL, it worked when I removed the trailing PM.

Finally, I added the following lines right after the 2nd line in the code above:

```
[dtFormatter setPMSymbol:@"PM"];
[dtFormatter setAMSymbol:@"AM"];
```

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 2):

```
MM/dd/Y hh:mm:ss a
```

Fore more info see: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: I have been trying that but I havent been able to use that, it always prints a null for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this will give you the required format..

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"];

// Conversion of NSString to NSDate
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:curDate];   //give what u want to give curDate
[formatter release];

// Conversion of NSDate to NSString
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]; //give date here
[formatter release];
```

This is the correct way if you want string from NSDate object...Now try it

Good Luck!

Comment: @Shumais Ul Haq  now try i had edited my code....and also sorry for my late response